# Possible to stream video directly from SQLite database in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have several video files stored as blobs in a SQLite database. I know that I can access this data using the SQLite API:

[sqlite3_blob_open](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_open)
[sqlite3_blob_read](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_blob_read)

The problem is that `MPMoviePlayerController` only accepts an `NSURL` object when initialized.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
               initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"path"]];
```

What I need to do (I think) is figure out how to wrap those SQLite API commands in a customized `NSURL` subclass of my own design to give to the `MPMoviePlayerController`. Thus, instead of trying to locate a resource on the web (or the file system), the movie player would instead stream the data directly from the database.

Any ideas? Of course, I realize that I could just package the video in the bundle as flat files, or, I could even copy the video out of the database at some point and put them directly on the device, but I don't want to do that - I want to stream directly from the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to store them in the db? Directory storage would likely be a better bet: you then aren't storing such large objects in the db, plus you can use a file:// url.

Comment: @joshpaul: our build process will be simplified if we can make this work, since we only need to worry about a single db file as opposed to multiple flat files. We have multiple apps (potentially dozens), each with a different number of videos, some with none at all. The db is created programatically ahead of time and bundled with the app. Copying them from the db to the file system is not desirable, since there are then 2 copies of every video on the device (one in the db, it's copy in the file system). Also, these apps must not rely on an internet connection.

Comment: It also occurs to me that this problem (and various others I have encountered) would be much easier to solve if Apple would publish their source code. +1 for Java ;)

Comment: The solution to your issue is not playing straight from the DB (which is not possible using MPMoviePlayerController) but using bundles instead of a SQLite db for distributing binary content.